# Eclipse tree bullets are invisible

Tags: eclipse, ide, darkmode

[image]

I would like to know if there is any way to change the color of the bulleted item in tree view in Eclipse while using a dark theme, they are almost invisible.

Try to use eclipse dark background, DevStyle dark theme, eclipse preferences, DPI settings, changing my Windows theme, and it seems like nothing can change the color of these bullets.

Comment: The "twistie" is drawn by the native control Eclipse uses on each platform. Eclipse doesn't provide a way to change the colour. So it would only be some option in the OS.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution for this? I have the EXACT same problem with the latest Eclipse on Windows.